# purrr::map does not work with pipe operator

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- tibble(
  i = rep(1:10, times = 5),
  t = rep(1:5, each = 10)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(y = rnorm(50))
```

I want to apply a function that takes data frame of each t as argument:

```
f <- function(df){
  return(lm(y ~ +1, data = df))
}
```

When I apply purrr::map for a nested data frame with pipe operator, I get error.

```
# does not work
df_nested <- df  %>% 
  nest(data = c(t, y)) %>% 
  rename(data_col = data) 

df_nested %>% 
  purrr::map(.x = .$data_col, .f = f)
```

On the other hand, when I do not use pipe operator, I get the desired result.

```
# Ok
purrr::map(.x = df_nested$data_col, .f = f)
```

To my understanding, both code should return the same result. What is wrong with the code with pipe operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipe already passes the previous value (`df_nested`) as the first argument to `map`. You may use `{}` to stop that from happening.

```
library(tidyverse)

df_nested %>% 
  {purrr::map(.x = .$data_col, .f = f)}
```

Another way would be to use -

```
df  %>% 
  nest(data_col = c(t, y)) %>%
  mutate(model = map(data_col, f))

#      i data_col         model 
#   <int> <list>           <list>
# 1     1 <tibble [5 × 2]> <lm>  
# 2     2 <tibble [5 × 2]> <lm>  
# 3     3 <tibble [5 × 2]> <lm>  
# 4     4 <tibble [5 × 2]> <lm>  
# 5     5 <tibble [5 × 2]> <lm>  
# 6     6 <tibble [5 × 2]> <lm>  
# 7     7 <tibble [5 × 2]> <lm>  
# 8     8 <tibble [5 × 2]> <lm>  
# 9     9 <tibble [5 × 2]> <lm>  
#10    10 <tibble [5 × 2]> <lm>
```